# Detect camera rotation at start when capturing video

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, video

I think the title itself is pretty self explainatory.

The reason I want to do this is that I'm getting the first frame of a video as a thumbnail, but depending on which way you hold the iPhone, it gets turned either 90* CCL or upside down.

Is there a way of detecting the camera orientation at the start of video capturing, like it is when taking a photo, or am I better of statically picking the most commonly used angle?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are getting the thumbnail through ALAsset bolck ?

Answer (score 2):

use :  UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrienation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

```
    NSLog(@"%i",deviceOrienation);

    on hit of camera_click_On() function...
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `shouldAutoRotateToInterface` in the root view controller

Answer (score 0):

See your camera will orientate as per your device orientation. So all you need to do is check for the device orientation

Comment: So it's possible to find the device orientation at the time, even when capturing a movie?
I've done it for photos but was doubtful it worked for video

Comment: Just gotta find out how to access the camera button, then I'll try and accept you answer!

Comment: Seriously can't come up with anything... Do you have any idea of how to access "when I press the camera button"?
Can't find it either in the docs or here on SO...
If you don't know I guess I'll have to make another question.